# Open phone call form with prefilled caller and direction using window.open

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

How could one open a phone call entity form so that direction is Incoming and that in "From" field there's a contact. I know already who is calling and I have the GUID. I know it's always contact. And I know that phone call is always incoming.

I have to use window.open function and pass those values in url. This site (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334375.aspx) does explain how to provide values for option sets and lookups, but in phone call "From" field is not a simple lookup but party list. And direction is not an option set but a Two options (if that makes any difference).

I have simply tried this

```
var extraqs = "directioncode=1&from=" + contactid;
    window.open("https://myserver.crm4.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=phonecall&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=" + encodeURIComponent(extraqs));
```

but I can't get it work. I have tried to fiddle with those values back and forward and sometimes I get no error but it doesn't work either. Sometimes I get System.Web.HttpUnhandledException. I know it's probably because the format is off.

Another option I was thinkin that I could probably pass those values in url to the form and then create a function to form onLoad event where I could more easily set those field. But it sounds a workaround to me.

But my question is can I, and if how, set up those two fields?

Answer (score 0):

A party list can not be set like a simple lookup.
Check out this blog post, it may guide you in setting party list

http://scaleablesolutions.com/open-new-activity-form-with-regarding-and-partylist-field-prefilled/

Comment: It uses Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm while I have to use window.open. But thanks for the answer. I solved this problem for now by passing values in url and then created a function in form's onload event that will then do the rest.